# Django (DRF) ManyToMany field choices / limit

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Working with Django REST Framework I am wondering if it's possible to limit the choices / options of a `ManyToMany` field on a model to a specific `QuerySet`?

Using the models below (scroll down to see models), I am curious if it's possible to define this limit in the definition of the model, to achieve the following:

```
# Having the following Employee instance
emp = Employee(...)

# Should return only the instances with value 'case' in EmployeeSubstitute.type field
emp.substitute_case.all()

# Should return only the instances with value 'phone' in EmployeeSubstitute.type field
emp.substitute_phone.all()
```

Models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    substitute_case = models.ManyToMany(through=EmployeeSubstitute, ...)
    substitute_phone = models.ManyToMany(through=EmployeeSubstitute, ...)
```

```
class EmployeeSubstitute(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(Employee, ...)
    to = models.ForeignKey(Employee, ...)
    type = models.CharField(choices=..., ...)  # choose between type 'case' and 'phone'
```

I see that there's the `limit_choices_to` parameter, but that's not what I am looking for, since that only effects the options shown when using a ModelForm or the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `ManyToManyField` returns related objects and as [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access) state

> By default, Django uses an instance of the Model._base_manager manager
> class when accessing related objects (i.e. choice.question), not the
> _default_manager on the related object. This is because Django needs to be able to retrieve the related object, even if it would otherwise
> be filtered out (and hence be inaccessible) by the default manager.
>
> If the normal base manager class (django.db.models.Manager) isn’t
> appropriate for your circumstances, you can tell Django which class to
> use by setting Meta.base_manager_name.
>
> Base managers aren’t used when querying on related models, or when
> accessing a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. For example, if
> the Question model from the tutorial had a deleted field and a base
> manager that filters out instances with deleted=True, a queryset like
> Choice.objects.filter(question__name__startswith='What') would include
> choices related to deleted questions.

So if I read it correctly, no, it's not possible.

When you do queries and have `through` in your `ManyToManyField`, Django complains you should run these queries on your `through` model, rather than the "parent". I can't find it in the docs but I remember seeing it a few times.

`substitute_case` and `substitute_phone` is something that belongs to substitute and it is it's type. So just do that instead of creating those columns in `Employee`.

```
from django.db import models


class SubstituteTypes(models.TextChoices):
    case = "case", "case"
    phone = "phone", "phone"


class EmployeeSubstituteQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def from_employee(self, e):
        return self.filter(_from=e)

    def case(self):
        return self.filter(type=SubstituteTypes.case)

    def phone(self):
        return self.filter(type=SubstituteTypes.phone)


class Employee(models.Model):
    substitute = models.ManyToManyField(through='EmployeeSubstitute', to='self')


class EmployeeSubstitute(models.Model):
    _from = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='a')
    to = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='b')
    type = models.CharField(choices=SubstituteTypes.choices, max_length=5, db_index=True)

    objects = EmployeeSubstituteQueryset.as_manager()
```

Then, once you get your `emp` object (or only its id), you can do

```
EmployeeSubstitute.objects.from_employee(emp).case().all()
```

which is designed in Django philosophy.

Comment: Thanks for this. I realize that I should learn to work with model managers. Reading the part you quoted I think what I originally sought to create may not be possible.